# Convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{u=0}^{k-1}\frac{r^{u}}{(k-u)^2}$

Tags: summation, power-series

Assume $r \in (0,1)$, I'm looking at the following sum, conjecture that it converges.

$$  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{u=0}^{k-1}\frac{r^{u}}{(k-u)^2} $$

This is very similar to the result of one [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4018863/278372), but I'm not sure how to cleanly deal with the $(k-u)^2$ denominator.

**Edit:**
Through playing around with Wolfram Mathematica, I'm getting

$$
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{u=0}^{k-1}\frac{r^{u}}{(k-u)^2} &=  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{u=1}^{k}\frac{r^{k-u}}{u^2}\\ &= 
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \left(\sum_{u=1}^{k} \int_{0}^{r} \left(\frac{k}{u^2} - \frac{1}{u}\right)x^{k-u-1} dx   \right) \\
   &=   \left(\sum_{u=1}^{\infty}   \int_{0}^{r} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{k}{u^2} - \frac{1}{u}\right)x^{k-u-1} dx   \right) \\
   &=   \left(\sum_{u=1}^{\infty}   \int_{0}^{r} \frac{x^{-u} (u x-u+1)}{u^2 (x-1)^2}  dx  \right) \\
   &=   \left( \int_{0}^{r} \frac{\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-x \log
    \left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)+\log
    \left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)}{(x-1)^2} dx   \right) \\
   &=   \left( -\frac{\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)}{r-1}+\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{r-1}{r}\right)+\log \left(\frac{1}{r}\right) \log
   \left(\frac{r-1}{r}\right)-\frac{\pi ^2}{6}   \right) \\
\end{align*}
$$
However, I can't validate whether all of the steps are valid and not misspecified by the software, especially the complex logarithms..

Comment: It does converges to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}\frac{1}{1-x}$

Comment: Since all terms are positive, just rearrange the series as a power series in $r$ and coefficients are partial sums of the familiar series for $\zeta(2)$.  So compare with $\sum_u\zeta(2)r^u$ shows it converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{u=0}^{k-1}\frac{r^{u}}{(k-u)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{r^{k-n}}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{r^{k-n}}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{1}{1-r}=\frac{\pi^2}{6(1-r)}$$ (similarly to your prior question, rearranging is valid because of nonnegativity of the terms).

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{u=0}^{k-1}\frac{r^u}{(k-u)^2} 
& = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{u=0}^{\infty}\frac{r^u[u<k]}{(k-u)^2}\\
& = \sum_{u=0}^\infty r^u\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{[u<k]}{(k-u)^2}\\
& = \sum_{u=0}^\infty r^u\sum_{k=u+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k-u)^2}\\
& = \sum_{u=0}^\infty r^u\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}
= \frac{1}{1-r}\frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

**Intuition:**

Consider the innermost sum. For large values of $k$, "most" of the terms of this sum will be negligibly small because of the exponential factor $r^u$. However, the "first few" terms of the inner sum will behave like $1/k^2$. It turns out that we can get away with considering only the "first few" terms of this inner sum (by "first few", I mean $\log(k)$ asymptotically, as we shall see momentarily) and noting that the contribution of the rest of the sum is insignificant compared to these first few values.

**Rigor:**

Define

$$s_k = \sum_{u=0}^{k-1} \frac{r^u}{(k-u)^2}$$

Let's break off the first $k'=\lfloor \log_r (1/k^3)\rfloor$ terms of this sum:

$$s_k = \color{red}{\sum_{u=0}^{k'} \frac{r^u}{(k-u)^2}} + \color{blue}{\sum_{u=k'+1}^{k-1} \frac{r^u}{(k-u)^2}}$$

For each term in the red sum, we have that

$$\frac{r^u}{(k-u)^2} \le \frac{1}{(k-k')^2}$$

meaning that the red sum satisfies

$$\color{red}{\sum_{u=0}^{k'} \frac{r^u}{(k-u)^2}} \le \frac{k'}{(k-k')^2}$$

For each term in the blue sum, we have that $r^u \le 1/k^3$, and hence

$$\frac{r^u}{(k-u)^2} \le \frac{1}{k^3}$$

Thus, the blue sum satisfies

$$\color{blue}{\sum_{u=k'+1}^{k-1} \frac{r^u}{(k-u)^2}} \le \frac{k-k'-2}{k^3} \le \frac{1}{k^2}$$

Thus, by combining our inequalities for the red and blue sums, we have that

$$s_k \le \frac{k'}{(k-k')^2} + \frac{1}{k^2}$$

Now, recalling that $k'=\lfloor \log_r (1/k^3)\rfloor$, it is easy to show that the $s_k$ is $\mathcal{O}(k^{-2}\log k)$, which is enough to show that it converges.